# can't get HTML content from textarea TinyMCE 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with TinyMCE 4 - I can't get HTML content from textarea. I am using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea', plugins: "charmap", toolbar: 'bold italic underline fontselect | charmap fontsizeselect alignleft aligncenter alignright', font_formats: 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier,monospace;AkrutiKndPadmini=Akpdmi-n', fontsize_formats: '7pt 8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 24pt 36pt', menu: 'none', statusbar: false, max_width: '10%' });</script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fomdpn").keyup(function(){
    var x = $("#fomdpn").tinyMCE().getContent();
    $("isiatas").html(x);
    });
    });
    </script>

    <form action="">
    <textarea name="fomdpn" id="fomdpn" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
    </form>
    <div id="isiatas" name="isiatas"></div>
```

please help. thanks

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use jquery and you didn't source jquery. Just do document.getElementById('fomdpn').value

Comment: I try to use this code:
var inputBox = tinymce.get('fomdpn').getContent();
console.log(temp);
inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('isiatas').innerHTML = inputBox;
}
but doesn't work

Comment: Hmm, try this then. tinyMCE.get('fomdpn').getContent();
Are you trying this in IE, because IE tends to have issues with console.log

Comment: I'm using google chrome. it's same dosen't work

Comment: @alex What is `inputBox`? It does not appear to be defined, so when you `getContent()` it will populate it with the content of the tinyMCE object. If it's not an element, you can't bind an event to it.

Comment: @DrBrad & Twisty : thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the elements on your page after TinyMCE is initialized, you will see different dom than what you are actually trying to register a keyup event upon.

Instead, add the event handler inside your TinyMCE setup as follows. Note the additional use of the `setup` I've added inside your `init` function. I also changed the selector to match your dom element ID.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tinymce.init({
        setup: function(editor) {
            editor.on('keyup', function() {
                $('#isiatas').html(editor.getContent());
            });
        },
        selector:'#fomdpn',
        plugins: "charmap",
        toolbar: 'bold italic underline fontselect | charmap fontsizeselect alignleft aligncenter alignright',
        font_formats: 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier,monospace;AkrutiKndPadmini=Akpdmi-n',
        fontsize_formats: '7pt 8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 24pt 36pt',
        menu: 'none',
        statusbar: false,
        max_width: '10%'
    });
});
```